# how to transform a char to a unicode java

Tags: java, unicode, char

```
import java.util.*;

public class Ex13 {

    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char firstL,secondL;

        System.out.println("insert first l");
        firstL=in.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("insert second l");
        secondL=in.next().charAt(0);
        if (){
             System.out.println("kk"); 

        }
    }
}
```

I need `firstL` and `secondL` to equal in the `if` section but I can't because the `firstL` and the `secondL` is a char type and I need to transform it to a Unicode so I can finish the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just check the value?

```
    char firstL,secondL;
    System.out.println("insert first l");
    firstL=in.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.println("insert second l");
    secondL=in.next().charAt(0);
    if (firstL == secondL){
         System.out.println("kk"); 
    }
```

Comment: Note that when `firstL` and `secondL` are `char`, using `charAt(0)` will work only for characters in the [Unicode BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), which can fit as-is in a single `char`. If you need to handle supplementary characters outside the BMP, which are encoded using multiple `char`s, then you need to change `firstL` and `secondL` to `int` and use `codePointAt(0)` instead.